# Imbalance dataset in regression problem

Tags: regression, unbalanced-classes

I know that there are several ways, such as sampling methods, to deal with the imbalance in classification.

However, I am dealing with the imbalance problem in regression settings.

Basically, I want to build a regression `F(X)` to predict `y` (say `y` range from 0 to 1).

However, the problem is most of the values of `y` are around `0.4-0.6`.

Hence, the predicted output (I used `xgboost`) almost lies around `0.5` --> it completely fail to predict extreme values such as 0.1 or 0.9.

What are some potential tricks that can be used to deal with the problem?

I tried over-sampling, i.e. add more instances of y<0.2 and y>0.8 to the model but it does not work.